# How to compile tiff images into xyz coordinates in a single text file?

Tags: linux, bash, terminal, tiff, cartesian-coordinates

I have limited experience with programming and I need your help.

The situation I am in is that I have a stack of black and white .tiff images (approx. 400 of 10 Mb each one) which I need to convert into xyz coordinates plus grayscale values and to compile all those in ONLY a single text file with x,y,z,grayscale (the z coordinates, this way: first image of the folder  z=0000, second image 0001...as many z coordinates as images in the folder).

I have a script (that I am pretty unfamiliar with, but I think it is done with Image Magick) which can do it but only for a single image at a time, and adds only the x, y coordinates and a value in grayscale, but no z.

The script , modified from the previous version I posted here (because now it uses Grayscale and stores only the values that I need) is:

```
## The exact format of the TXT image is defined by the convert command, then 'tail' is used to junk the header, 
## 'tr' to character replace every non-number character with a single space, so that the later 'while' can read 
## it easily, junking any comment numbers that may have been left.

convert -depth 8 -colorspace RGB $1 txt:- |
    tail -n +2 | tr -cs '0-9.\n'  ' ' |
    while read x y Gray junk; 
    do
    if [ "$Gray" -eq 0 ]; then
        echo "$x,$y $Gray"
        done
```

To run it I put in the linux terminal:

```
chmod +x img.sh
```

And after that (I selected the same name as the image but with .txt as filename):

```
./img.sh pic0000.tif > pic0000.txt
```

Also I tried to change it to do it all at once, replacing the line:

```
convert -depth 8 -colorspace RGB $1 txt:- |
```

with

```
convert -depth 8 -colorspace RGB $* txt:- |
```

and putting this in the terminal

```
chmod +x ./img.sh
./img.sh *.tif > *.txt
```

And now it puts all the files in one with x y Grayscale, but I cannot add the z values.

By the way,it takes a long time to create the txt file.

The first lines of the final XYZ file must be, for example:

```
0 0 0 value in greyscale 
1 0 0 value in greyscale
...
and the last: 
3095 2951 400 value in greyscale
```

Would you give me any clues, ideas or solutions to do it? Any help would be sincerely appreciated.

Comment: Is the script in fortran?

Comment: add some source code also if you have done anything?

Comment: Does your employer have any Fortran expertise in-house? It doesn't seem reasonable they dump urgent programming jobs on biologists without programming experience.

Comment: The script is in emacs, but I do not completely understand it. For some reasons I am not able to share the source codes. I tried to do it with the second part, using the file names as places in the z coordinate. But I could not succeed, neither in that nor in compiling all the resulting text files into a single one.

Comment: Hi there. I removed the note on deadlines deliberately, as they sometimes have the unintended effect of discouraging people from answering - remember that helpers here are volunteers who answer, broadly for fun, in their free time. I see you've rolled that back. Remember also that notes on deadlines/urgency aren't very interesting to the hundreds of readers that will see your question after the deadline passes, which is another reason why we like to take them out.

Comment: Why can you only use Fortran 90?  What’s the format of the XY-file, and what’s the format of the XYZ-file you should be generating?

Comment: Ok, thank you @halfer.

Comment: I said that I have to use Fortran 90 because It is the only programming language that I know a bit and don't have time to learn a new language now, but if you know some other easy way to do it I will appreciate it too. And the format of the XY-file and the final XYZ-file should be ".txt"

Comment: What is the layout of the data in each file?

Comment: Each file is an image, like "image0003", and the format of the XY-file and the final XYZ-file should be a ".txt" with 4 columns (x,y,z, value in greyscale)

Comment: Can you please add to your post 1. the command you would use to convert Image0003 to an XY-file, 2. the first few and last few lines of the XY-file, 3. the filename of the XY-file, and 4. What the corresponding lines of the XYZ-file should be?

Comment: Ok, i talked to the author and now i can post the code.

Comment: Do you mean that you have tiff files named with "image0000" to "image0400" (a total of 401 files) and already have the corresponding text files "image0000.txt" to "image0400.txt" (generated by the above script)? Does each line contain only one set of (x,y,r,g,b) values per line? Also, does the value of z correspond precisely to the integer in the file name ? (for example, z = 400 for image0400.txt?)

Comment: To @roygvib:  Yes to everything, but I don't have the values of z yet, and I precisely want the values of z to correspond to the integer in the file name, and the script can only produce one text file at a time...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although Fortran can also be used, a shell (bash) script can do this rather directly. For example, assuming that "conv.sh" has the following

```
allout="alldata.out"   # name of a combined XYZ file
[ -f $allout ] && rm -i $allout

for inpfile in image*.txt ; do

    echo "processing $inpfile"
    z=$( echo $inpfile | sed -e 's/image\([0-9]*\)\.txt/\1/' )
    echo "z = $z"

    outfile=data${z}.out    # name of each XYZ file

    awk -F'[, ]' -v z=$z '{ printf( "%5d,%5d,%5d %16.6f\n", $1, $2, z, 0.2989 * $3 + 0.5870 * $4 + 0.1140 * $5 ) }' $inpfile > $outfile

    cat $outfile >> $allout
done
```

we run it in the directory where the data files (image*.txt) exist:

```
$ chmod +x ./conv.sh
$ ./conv.sh
```

Then we obtain a set of output files (data0000.out, ..., data0400.out) plus their combined file (alldata.out). Please note that I have assumed that "x,y" and "r,g,b" in the input files are separated by only one whitespace, and that the grayscale is defined as

```
0.2989 * R + 0.5870 * G + 0.1140 * B
```

But the definition seems not unique (for example, the [Wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grayscale) shows 0.2126 * R + 0.7152 * G + 0.0722 * B) so please choose your desired definition.

---

Edit: You can also add z-value directly using for loop as follows:

```
output="output.txt"
rm -f $output   # combined XYZ file

for (( z=0 ; z <= 400; z++ )); do
    inpfile=pic${z}.tif
    convert -depth 8 -colorspace RGB $inpfile txt:- | tail -n +2 | tr -cs '0-9.\n' ' ' | while read x y Gray junk; do if [ "$Gray" -eq 0 ]; then echo "$x,$y,$z $Gray" done >> $output
done
```

If the input names are something like "pic0000.tif" to "pic0400.tif", you may want to pad zeros in front of z-value, for example,

```
for (( z=0 ; z <= 400; z++ )); do

    if (( z < 10 ))   ; then n=000$z ; fi
    if (( z < 100 ))  ; then n=00$z  ; fi
    if (( z < 1000 )) ; then n=0$z   ; fi

    inpfile=pic${n}.tif    # "n" is the file index from 0000 to 0400

    convert ....  # same as above
done
```

Comment: For more info, "%5d,%5d,%5d %16.6f\n" in printf() specifies the format of output xyz + greyscale data, where 5 means the width of integer output and 16.6 means the width of floating-point number with 6 significant digits. If you don't need commas between x,y,z, then pls change this to "%5d %5d %5d %16.6f\n", for example.

Comment: I prefer 0.2989 * R + 0.5870 * G + 0.1140 * B,  I'm not responding because I'm working on it, but looks very good, thanks a lot!.

Comment: If you want no white spaces between x,y, and z (i.e. comma-separated), plz try using "%0d,%0d,%0d %16.6f\n" (where 0 means "zero"). If not working, plz let me know (we can also write Fortran counterpart but it becomes somewhat longer...) Cheers :)

Comment: Thanks.  I was going to write basically the same script (although maybe in `perl`), but you beat me to it.

Comment: Hmm a simple "%d,%d,%d %16.6f\n" may be sufficient for the latter purpose... plz google for "printf format" etc :) @Lorehead no problem :)

Comment: Yes!! It works! Thank you very much @roygvib, answer clicked!

Comment: Your script works very well once I have the text files in a folder, but if possible, I would know how to do it in one single script, convert the files to one file in .txt with the z axis (data of one picture, then the next, then...) What should I do? I wrote again the original script and now it put all the image data only with xy in a single file (It is in the next comment) How do I merge it with yor script?

Comment: This is the script: convert -depth 8 -colorspace Gray $* txt:- |
    tail -n +2 | tr -cs '0-9.\n'  ' ' |
      while read x y Gray junk;
        do
      if [ "$Gray" -eq 0 ]; then
        z=$[z+1]
        echo "$x $y $z $Gray"
      fi
       done

Comment: and to run it i used $ chmod +x script1.sh
                               $ ./script1.sh *.tif > *.txt

Comment: (Sorry for posting it with comments)

Comment: Sorry again, this shouldn't appear in the script, please, erase "z=$[z+1] "

Comment: @trıtog, Hmm... I have read your comments several times but still can't understand your new goal... So could you edit your original post to add more detailed information? Alternatively, you can also ask a new question here http://unix.stackexchange.com by posting your current shell script and explanation of your (new) goal, because in that forum a number of people are extremely familiar with file handling:) For example, I have posted this question before http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/215327/sorting-a-file-with-integer-in-parentheses-with-no-space and got answer in a few minutes :D

Comment: I guess "./script1.sh *.tif > *.txt" will not work because the information of z values (originally contained in the file names) is lost by merging them (also note that the redirection ">" does not work for multiple files after ">"). I have added some potentially useful bash constructs, so plz use it if necessary.

Comment: Thank you for all your advices @roygvib, I updated the question.

Comment: @trıtog I guess by adding for-loop over z-values and adding $z, you can probably get a combined XYZ file (see Edit above). Also, plz note that the convert command (from ImageMagick) has an option to generate grayscale data, for example, "convert -type Grayscale pic0000.jpg txt:- > pic0000.txt". Though this can be used only for each file, it is convenient to get a grayscale image.

Comment: @trıtog Sorry, in the first example in the Edit, you will get wrong file names like pic0.tif to pic400.tif. If you want file names like pic0000.tif to pic0400.tif, you many need to pad zeros in front of z. Plz see the second example in the Edit.

Comment: That's all. Here is the final script working as I need. Thank you very much guys.  (It is in the next comment). From .tiff grayscale to .txt in one file, with z coordinates, like this:
x y z Gray (always zero). To know when one pic ends and another begins, see that the "z" value changes
To compile it:
chmod +x ./script.sh
and then:           
./script.sh>xyzfile.txt
Don't forget to have in the folder ONLY the pictures and the script.

Comment: #!/bin/bash
z=0
for i in pic*; do
z=$[$z+1]
convert -depth 8 -colorspace Gray $i txt:- |
    tail -n +2 | tr -cs '0-9.\n'  ' ' |
    while read x y Gray junk;
        do
      if [ "$Gray" -eq 0 ]; then
        echo "$x $y $z $Gray"
      fi
        done
done